# Script won't run in cron but runs fine in root shell

Tags: shell, cron, python

**My Problem:** I have a python script that runs fine when run manually but does not complete when run using cron.  My script fails in cron because it contains pexpect commands that require an interactive shell (I think).

Sample code:

```
p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', timeout=3, searchwindowsize=-1)
p.expect(host + '@root:')
```

**My Question:** Are there environment variables I can pass into cron that will allow my cron job to run in an interactive shell?

Comment: You can pass `-i` to bash, but `stdin` will never be a terminal from cron. What are you really trying to accomplish with this expect script?

Comment: if the password is plain text I'd avoid this. can't you use `public/private keys`

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The script tries to SSH to a host using several fake usernames and passwords.  It's supposed to be denied each time.  Pexpect is used to interact with the SSH server and read the "Permission Denied" messages.  @gwillie, you're absolutely right, keys would be the normal way of doing this, but my script is supposed to check wrong passwords so I don't actually want it to get in.

Comment: Your original question mentioned environment variables; you could run `env` in both a working- and a non-working environment and compare the two. Also, can you give any more details as to what happens with it fails? A Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example (http://sscce.org/) would be good.

Comment: What are 1) the command you're passing to cron, 2) the command line you're typing at the shell prompt, and 3) the traceback you get on failure (cron should e-mail it to you)?